# Stop the Outlook 2016 Reminders window from being "always on top"

Tags: ms-office, calendar, reminders

It looks like Outlook 2016's calendar Reminders window is set to "always on top" and there's nothing I can do about it. But that seems crazy. Googling isn't finding other people complaining of the same thing, and I can't find a setting for it, so I wonder if it's specific to my machine. Can anyone confirm?

Is there a way to force it to stop being always on top? Maybe an app that can change window behaviors? Or an AppleScript option?

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to the Outlook app then Hide (⌘H) Outlook, the Reminders window will be hidden along with the rest of the app.

If you switch back to Outlook again the Reminders will return to being always on top, so it will occlude other apps again if you switch back away from Outlook other than by Hiding it.

(I figured this out from one of the far more numerous complaints about Reminders NOT interrupting work, where [KiltedTim recommended not hiding Outlook](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31363705#message31363705))

Comment: Interesting - you're essentially saying "if you hide Outlook, the window won't be always on top anymore... because it won't be visible at all". That's actually almost a sufficient answer for me, except that I usually keep Outlook in its own "space" and so I can't just switch to it anymore by swiping to that space. It's a better idea than any I've had, though :)

Comment: @NathanArthur, I hadn't thought of that, and had to wait for another reminder to test; that's really weird that you can't move the reminders to the same space as the rest of the app.